# Mongodb query need improvement

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Hello Everyone,

I am working on a project and I am using MongoDB as my database. I have 2 collections as mentioned below:

comments

```
[{
    "_id":1,
    "name":"testname1",
    "email":"testmail1",
    "user_id":1
},
{
    "_id":2,
    "name":"testname1",
    "email":"testmail1",
    "user_id":1
},
{
    "_id":3,
    "name":"testname1",
    "email":"testmail1",
    "user_id":2
},
{
    "_id":4,
    "name":"testname1",
    "email":"testmail1",
    "user_id":2
},
{
    "_id":5,
    "name":"testname1",
    "email":"testmail1",
    "user_id":2
}]
```

and users

```
[{
    "_id":1,
    "name":"testname1",
    "email":"testmail1",
},
{
    "_id":2,
    "name":"testname1",
    "email":"testmail1",
},
]
```

I want the result in the below format:

```
[{
    "_id":1,
    "name":"testname1",
    "email":"testmail1",
    "comment_ids":[1, 2]
},
{
    "_id":2,
    "name":"testname1",
    "email":"testmail1",
    "comment_ids":[3,4,5]
}]
```

Theses are test collections I don't want to change my collection structure.
Can anybody help me how I can achieve my desired result.
I tried the following query:

```
db.users.aggregate([{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: "comments",
       localField: "_id",
       foreignField: "user_id",
       as: "data"
     }
    }
])
```

The output of the query is:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : "testname1",
    "email" : "testmail1",
    "data" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "msg" : "test",
            "email" : "testmail1",
            "user_id" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "msg" : "test",
            "email" : "testmail1",
            "user_id" : 1
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "name" : "testname1",
    "email" : "testmail1",
    "data" : [
        {
            "_id" : 3,
            "msg" : "test",
            "email" : "testmail1",
            "user_id" : 2
        },
        {
            "_id" : 4,
            "msg" : "test",
            "email" : "testmail1",
            "user_id" : 2
        },
        {
            "_id" : 5,
            "msg" : "test",
            "email" : "testmail1",
            "user_id" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is the output of your above query?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I have  updated the question with query output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `.dot` notation with the `_id`

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "comments",
    "localField": "_id",
    "foreignField": "user_id",
    "as": "comment_ids"
  }},
  { "$addFields": { "comment_ids": "$comment_ids._id" }}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no need to use lookup as you already have email and name in your comments collection. You can directly use `group`. It will be much faster compared to the `lookup`. Here is the example

```html
db.getCollection('comments').aggregate([
{
    $group:{
    "_id":"$user_id",
        "name":{$first:"$name"},
        "email":{$first:"$email"},
   comments:{$addToSet:"$_id"}
   }
}
])
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But these are the test collections sample my actual collections are totally different. Above answer fulfill my all requirements.